# Make content stretch with sidebar

Tags: css

Before I start I will categorically state I have searched for an answer both here and on Google but no solutions have worked for me. I have tried display: table-cell, inline-block, all types of overflow but nothing is working.

My sidebar will 99% of the time be longer than the content. I would just set a min-height, however I have 3 different sidebars depending on what user is logged in. One is about 4 x longer than the other 2, so setting heights wouldn't work.

```
<div class="container">
   <?php include ('sidebar.php'); ?>
     <div class="content">
       content
     </div>
</div>
```

My CSS currently:

```
.container {
width: 1210px;
background: #<?php echo $contentbgcolor; ?>;  /* content bg colour */
margin-left: auto;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
border-right:1px solid #000;
border-left:1px solid #000;
margin-right: auto;
overflow: auto;
}
.content {
padding: 10px;
float:left;
}
.sidebar {  
width: 250px;   
overflow: auto;
position: absolute;
float:left;
padding: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
}
```

[image]
Would appreciate any assistance.

Full HTML example:

```
    <div class="container">         
    <div class="sidebar">
        <!-- Time Sidebox -->
            <div class="sidebarBoxHeader">
                Metropolis Time
            </div>
            <div class="sidebarBox">
                <div id="clock" style="text-align:center; font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px;"></div><div style="text-align:center;">Sunday 5th April</div>
            </div>
        <!-- End time sidebox -->
        <!-- Current game sidebox -->
    <div class="sidebarBoxTitle">
        Current Game(s)
    </div>
    <div class="sidebarBox" align="center">
        <div align='center'>No games currently.</div>    
        <div style="margin-top: 10px;"><a href="sched_sunday.php"><i class="fa fa-external-link"></i> View today's schedule</a></div>
     </div>
<!-- end current game box -->
<!-- Current game sidebox -->
    <div class="sidebarBoxTitle">
         Staff on Duty
    </div>
    <div class="sidebarBox" align="center">
        <div align='center'>No staff on duty.</div><div style="margin-top: 10px;"><a href="roster.php"><i class="fa fa-external-link"></i> View full staff roster</a></div>     
     </div>
<!-- end current game box -->
<!-- Start Links Sidebox -->
    <div class="sidebarBoxTitle">
        Dashboard
    </div>
    <div class="sidebarBox borderBottom">
        <ol style="list-style: none; display: inline; -webkit-padding-start: 0px;">
                    <li><a href="adm_index.php"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Admin Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="adm_games.php"><i class="fa fa-gamepad"></i> Game Management</a></li>
            <li style="padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;"><b>Schedule Options</b></li>
            <li><a href="adm_customize.php"><i class="fa fa-paint-brush"></i> Customize Schedule</a>
            <li><a href="adm_pages.php"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit Pages</a></li>
            <li style="padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;"><b>Event Management</b></li>
            <li><a href="adm_sched_events.php"><i class="fa fa-trophy"></i> Manage Events</a>
            <li><a href="adm_events_new.php"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add New Event</a>
            <li style="padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;"><b>Staff Management</b></li>
            <li><a href="adm_staff.php"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Staff Management</a></li>
            <li><a href="adm_staff_roster.php"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Roster Management</a></li>
            <li><a href="adm_sponsor.php"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> Sponsor Management</a></li>
            <li style="padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;"><b>Administration</b></li>
            <li><a href="admin_users.php"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> User Management</a></li>
            <li><a href="admin_permissions.php"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i> Permission Groups</a></li>
            <li><a href="admin_pages.php"><i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i> Page Permissions</a></li>
            <li style="padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;"><b>Staff Links</b></li>
            <li><a href="staff_games.php"><i class="fa fa-gamepad"></i> Your Sponsored Games</a></li>
            <li><a href="staff_hosts.php"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Your Sponsored Hosts (Weekly)</a></li>
            <li><a href="staff_event_hosts.php?Event="><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Your Sponsored Hosts (Event)</a></li>
            <li><a href="staff_roster.php"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Your Staff Roster</a></li>
            <li style="padding-top: 10px;"><a href="user_settings.php"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i> Account Settings</a></li>
            <li><a href="logout.php"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Log Out [&nbsp;admin&nbsp;]</a></li>
                    </ol>
    </div>

<!-- End links sidebox -->   
     </div>         
     <div class="content">
<div style="padding-bottom:10px;">

<form name="form1" method="get" action="">
                <select name="Event" required style="width:257px; height:25px; font-size:18px; border:1px solid #000;">
<option value="">Change Event</option>
<option value='NewEvent'>NewEvent</option><option value='oneady'>oneady</option><option value='Test'>Test</option><option value='Testing'>Testing</option></select>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" class="buttonRefresh" value="&#xf021; "></div>
    <div class="contentBoxHeader">
        Your Sponsored Hosts for  event
    </div>
        <div class="schedBox">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td width="50%" class="schedHeader">Host Name</td>
                <td width="50%" class="schedHeader">Prize Sets Required</td>                
            </tr>
                    <tr>
        <td class="schedHeader" style="border-top: 1px solid #000;">Total Prize Sets Required:</td>
        <td class="schedHeader" style="border-top: 1px solid #000;"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
        <div class="footerTxt">
            Schedule Interface Version 1.0 Beta.
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post a complete code example. We don't need to see the PHP, however the rendered HTML would help.

Comment: Have you tried removing `position: absolute;`?

Comment: If I do that, it pushes the content div to the bottom of the sidebar. So in effect yes it works but not in the way I need it lol

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not seeing that http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/460Lmh3z/

Comment: You know what, if I add a width to the content div and remove position: absolute it works :) This has been bugging me for hours! If you wanna answer I'll +1 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the `position:absolute` on the sidebar [appears to resolve the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/460Lmh3z/).

Answer (score 0):

Try using bootstrap. it responsive design and you can simply set your div width with it. download it [here](http://getbootstrap.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm not a fan of bootstrap. Cheers.